# Java: join the values of a map containing sets

Tags: java, dictionary, set

Consider the following pseudo `Map<String, Set<String>>`:

```
{
    "1": ["A", "B"],
    "2": ["A", "C"],
    "3": ["D", "B", "A", "C"],
    "4": ["C", "A", "B"],
    "5": ["A", "B"],
}
```

What is the best way to join the value Sets into a single Set (above example should be `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`). The order of the resulting set does not matter.

I know that I can to something like this:

```
Collection<Set<String>> values = myMap.values();
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();

for (Set<String> v : values) {
    for (String s : v) {
        if (!unique.contains(s)) unique.add(s);
    }
}
```

But it feels kind of ugly and I'm wondering if there is a better (and more "built-in") way of doing this?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to check if the set already contains the value you are about to add. The set doesn't care and will simply ignore if the value is already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Set.addAll(Collection)` method; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
Collection<Set<String>> values = myMap.values();
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>();

for (Set<String> v : values) {
    unique.addAll(v);
}
```

The logic should be self-evident.

Meta-lesson: it is a good idea to familiarize yourself with the capabilities of the APIs that you use by skim-reading the javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to check whether a `Set` already contains the value which you are about to add. That's why you'd want to use a set in the first place.

> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

from [`Set#add(E)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-)

Keeping that in mind, the only thing you will have to do is actually go through your `Set`s and combine the values into a single set without having to worry about duplicates.

One solution via `addAll()` was already provided, so I thought I would provide an alternative solution using Java 8 streams:

```
Set<String> unique = myMap.values() // gets the values (all sets) from the map
    .stream()                       // stream of values
    .flatMap(Set::stream)           // flattens all sets (in values) in to single stream
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());   // collects the values into single set
```